# force full width issue when use RTL

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use advanced grid plugin and I set direction: "rtl" in css file im trying get force full width with this code

```
<?php if($force_full_width == 1) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function force_full_width_<?php echo $advanced_id; ?>() {
          var p = $(".standard-body .full-width .advanced-grid-<?php echo $advanced_id; ?>");
          if(p.size() > 0) {
               p.width($('body').width());
               p.css("left", "0px");
               var position = p.offset();
               p.css("left", "-" + position.left + "px");
               p.find(".container").css("padding-left", position.left);
               p.find(".container").css("padding-right", position.left);
          }

          var s = $(".standard-body .fixed .advanced-grid-<?php echo $advanced_id; ?>");
          if(s.size() > 0) {
               s.width($('.standard-body .fixed .pattern').width());
               s.css("left", "0px");
               var position = s.offset();
               var position2 = $('.standard-body .fixed .pattern').offset();
               var position3 = position.left-position2.left;
               s.css("left", "-" + position3 + "px");
               s.find(".container").css("padding-left", position3);
               s.find(".container").css("padding-right", position3);
          }

          var b = $(".standard-body .fixed2 .advanced-grid-<?php echo $advanced_id; ?>");
          if(b.size() > 0) {
               b.width($('body').width());
               b.css("left", "0px");
               var position = b.offset();
               b.css("left", "-" + position.left + "px");
               b.find(".container").css("padding-left", position.left);
               b.find(".container").css("padding-right", position.left);
          }

          var c = $(".fixed-body .advanced-grid-<?php echo $advanced_id; ?>");
          if(c.size() > 0) {
               c.width($('.fixed-body .main-fixed').width());
               c.css("left", "0px");
               var position = c.offset();
               var position2 = $('.fixed-body .main-fixed').offset();
               var position3 = position.left-position2.left;
               c.css("left", "-" + position3 + "px");
               c.find(".container").css("padding-left", position3);
               c.find(".container").css("padding-right", position3);
          }
     }

     force_full_width_<?php echo $advanced_id; ?>();

     $(window).resize(function() {
          force_full_width_<?php echo $advanced_id; ?>();
     });
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

in ltr its work good like this image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9rTi.jpg]

but in rtl language get empty space like this image

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ny2hvt5.jpg]

how make this work good with rtl direction

Comment: Since this seems a style issue, I request you put up a working code demo (ie. codepen or the like), so we can use the inspector to find out what is going on and supply edits to fix the issue. At a general glance, the width isn't correctly calculated.

Comment: Can you provide CSS and HTML please? This is likely where the issue is.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [MCVE]

Comment: How is this question even upvoted if it doesn't contain relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make sure what is the actual problem as there is no HTML provided, so we simply have no way to know what part of Javascript is working on which part of the screen capture.

However, for some hints to the correct direction, it seems that using Javascript for this kind of styling is over-complicating the problem. This problem should be able to be solved with mainly CSS, with Javascript just show/hide the desired div on language change. Simply use a container with 100% width, then put the elements inside the container should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The provided file is the javascript of the slider. But you need an HTML code in order to insert the slider to the HTML page.

Then you can change the width to 100% from the HTML code itself.

If you could provide the html code, the relevant issue could be solved.